# Laravel: OrderBy not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all of the records in modal `Roleplay` order by the `payslips_collected ASC` (ascending).

Ascending is meant to start at the lowest value and go up. I am not getting that... here is my result of a table I made.

```
+----+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| ID |    Username      | Shifts |  Completed  |  Registered     | Website Login   | Client Login | Last Seen |
+----+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1  |  Danny Fure      |   29   | 1 year ago  |  43 minutes ago | 43 minutes ago  | 1 second ago |           |
| 2  |  James Mack      |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 3  |  Peter Barlow    |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 4  |  Adam Chapman    |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 5  |  Danny Burrows   |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 6  |  Kieran Root     |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 8  |  Ashton David    |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 9  |  Someone Special |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 10 |  Kelly Clark     |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
| 11 |  Abbie Grove     |   0    | 1 year ago  |  1 second ago   | 2 days ago      | 1 second ago |           |
+----+------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I'm sorry its a bit messed up, it didn't format correctly. But anyway, the main issue is its showing in `DESC` order, (descending) showing the highest before the lowest.

Can anyone tell me why its doing this?

Raw Query:

```
select * from `users` where exists (select * from `srp_user_statistics` where `users`.`id` = `srp_user_statistics`.`user_id` order by `payslips_collected` asc)
```

Code:

```
$players = Player::whereHas('roleplay', function ($query) use($orderType) {
    $query->orderBy('payslips_collected', $orderType);
});
```

Comment: It actually doesn't matter in Laravel, but it was lowercase anyway.

Comment: just show us your table .As here we are not getting about `payslips_collected`

Comment: Bibhudatta, payslips_collected belongs to the `srp_user_statistics` table, that's clear to see in the raw query. I don't think you need anything more than that.

Comment: Why don't you use raw query instead of all these. Like DB::select('your Query');

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting like that as you are using **order by** for the **sub-query** not for the **main select query** so try to write order by out side you sub-query
 Like this

```
$players = Player::whereHas('roleplay', function ($query) use($orderType) {
    $query->orderBy('payslips_collected', $orderType);
})->orderBy('id', $orderType);
```

**Edit:-**

```
select `users`.* from `users` join `srp_user_statistics` on `users`.`id` = `srp_user_statistics`.`user_id`
order by `srp_user_statistics.payslips_collected` asc
```

Comment: I get this error when I try this? SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payslips_collected' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `srp_user_statistics` where `users`.`id` = `srp_user_statistics`.`user_id` order by `payslips_collected` desc) order by `payslips_collected` desc limit 10)

Comment: `'payslips_collected'` is column is not in your user table so this error came give the column name from your use table then you will get the value

Comment: That isn't what I want to do.. I want to get the column payslips_collected FROM the Roleplay table.. not the users table.

Comment: ` exists (select * from srp_user_statistics where users.id = srp_user_statistics.user_id order by payslips_collected desc)` this a condition it will give true or false value not your data to do that you need to join too table .check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: I don't want to change my query, my query is fine (syntax wise) its just the issue of Laravel returning it DESC when I select ASC.

Comment: the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460324/converting-a-complicated-query-to-laravels-eloquent#45460324

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$players = Player::has('roleplay')
    ->orderBy('payslips_collected', $orderType)
    // ...
```

Comment: I call ->get() later on in the function. There isn't any need for this, and even if I did forget to call ->get() I would get an error, not this kind of issue.

Comment: @distributi0n The problem with your code is that your `order by` clause is inside the `subquery` which is ignored so you've to call it outside.

Comment: I can't call it outside of that query because payslips_collected doesn't belong to the Player modals table, it belongs to Roleplay modals table. I receive an error telling me the column doesn't exist when trying.

Comment: @distributi0n the results follows the main query order which is fetching from `users` table not from `payslips_collected` so you've to order them according to the `user` table which is being returned.

Comment: Zayn payslips_collected  is the column, not the table. I am trying to get * FROM users table ORDER BY payslips_collected but payslips_collected is in the relation "Roleplay"'s table.

Comment: Try the edited query you will get you desired o/p :)

Comment: That's getting payslips_collected from table "users" which is the table of Player modal, I don't want that I was to get it from the "Roleplay" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the results collection:

```
$sorted_players = $players->sortByDesc('payslips_collected');
```

Or simply reverse your actual results

```
$sorted_players = $players->reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (I don't know when) Laravel will have its own default sort order come in front of your own...which obviously causes issues.

A trick to solve this is to reset any previous orders in the query with this line before you add your own:

```html
$query->getQuery()->orders = null;
```