# Converting a complicated query to Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering how I would go about converting this query to Laravel?

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN srp_user_statistics ON users.id = srp_user_statistics.user_id ORDER BY srp_user_statistics.payslips_collected DESC LIMIT 2
```

"users" table is in a modal called Player and the srp_user_statistics table is in a modal called Roleplay which is a relationship of modal Player called "roleplay"

I tried this, but its returning DESC even when selecting ASC:

```
$players = Player::whereHas('roleplay', function ($query) use($orderType) {
    $query->orderBy('payslips_collected', $orderType);
})->get();
```

Comment: This is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459125/laravel-orderby-not-working/45459529#45459529 i just give you this solution ?

Comment: Sorry? This is not the same question

Answer (score 0):

using Larvel Query Builder:

```
$record = DB::table('users')
->innerJoin('srp_user_statistics', 'users.id', '=', 'srp_user_statistics.user_id')
->orderBy('payslips_collected', 'DESC')
->limit(2)
->get();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error? (1/1) BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::innerJoin() in Builder.

Comment: @JoshHallow try use only "join" instead of "innerJoin".

Comment: Yes, try using join.

Comment: Again, make sure to have `use illuminate\support\facades\DB` at the top of ur controller. It allow u to use the DB query class